# Paths work in wamp but not on production server for slim framework

Tags: php, wamp, slim

Here is my simple slim index file:

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  session_start();

  // Include all controllers
  foreach(glob("controllers/*.php") as $controller)
  {
    include_once $controller;
  }

  // Include all models
  foreach(glob("models/*.php") as $model)
  {
    include_once $model;
  }

  include_once 'libs/ApiService.php';
  include_once 'libs/AuthService.php';
  include_once 'libs/HelperService.php';

  // Instantiate a new Slip application
  $app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'debug' => true,
    'corpKey'   => '2930850',
    'corpVcode' => '..',
    'ceoCID'    => '92311241'
  ));

  // GET CONTROLLERS
  $home = new Home($app);

  $app->get('/', function () use ($home, $app) {
    $home->index();
  });

  $app->run();
```

Now my home controller looks like this:

```
<?php

use Respect\Validation\Validator;

class Home
{

  // Slim application instance
  private $app;

  public function __construct($app)
  {
    $this->app = $app;
  }

  /**
  * Render home page
  */
  public function index()
  {
    // Fetch all articles
    $articles = Article::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();

    $this->app->render("../view/home/index.php", array('articles' => $articles));
  }
}
```

The line `$this->app->render()` gives an error that file index.php does not exist even tho it does. I also tried replacing that with an absolute path and with just `view/home/index.php` but always the same problem.

The application works on wamp but not on the production server.

1 Thing I noticed was I can use this style of include_once on wamp but not on server:

```
include_once '/libs/ApiService.php'; // Works on WAMP but not on Server
```

Comment: Is app server on Linux?

Comment: Yes the server is linux based.

Comment: Where is ApiService.php located? My guess is you have to remove the first slash from your include_once line.

Comment: @zjd Thats not the problem. And yes without the / it works the problem it wont load other files in my controllers. My controllers are in folder root/controllers and my views are in root/views.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @zjd Type: RuntimeException
Message: View cannot render `../view/home/index.php` because the template does not exist
File: /home/u379225821/public_html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/View.php
Line: 272

Comment: My assumption is that you are having wrong cases in file names. Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: @Gaurav like what the path is correct the folder names are corrrect and the file is there.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend two things:

**Define an `APP_PATH` constant to help mitigate relative path frustrations**

I've been developing in PHP for more than a decade, and this kind of thing still trips me up.  One of the ways I deal with it is by defining an `APP_PATH` directory and setting everything else relative to that.  At the top of your `index.php`, you could add:

```
define('APP_PATH', realpath(dirname(__DIR__)));
```

Now you know, 100% for sure, that your `APP_PATH` on your Linux server is `/home/u379225821`.  If you'd prefer your `APP_PATH` to be `public_html`, change that to:

```
define('APP_PATH', realpath(__DIR__));
```

It doesn't really matter so much what it is, it matters that you know exactly where you are.  I *highly* recommend experimenting with that, going so far as to debug by adding a `die(var_dump(APP_PATH));` directly after your definition to make sure you are where you think you are.  Since you're developing on Windows and deploying on Linux, *quadruple check* the result of that definition on both servers.

**Set your templates directory when you instantiate your Slim app**

By default, Slim View looks for templates in `./templates`, relative to your `index.php` (Look for the **templates.path** setting in the [Application Settings documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Application-Settings)).  Based on your directory structure (from the error), that would be `/home/u379225821/public_html/templates`.  You're telling Slim to look for your `index.php` template in `/home/u379225821/public_html/./templates/../view/home`.  Confused yet?  Me too.

Solve that by adding a 'templates.path' key and setting the path to your `../view` directory, wherever that is.  Use your new `APP_PATH` constant to make it easier to set.  Then, when you call `render` in your `Home` controller, you can simply call `$this->app->render('home/index.php');`.